# Binding resize event to a custom object with Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, jquery-events

I'm trying to write an object in JS. This object needs to recalculate some values whenever the browser window resizes. I'm trying to do that by binding a function to the event ("resize"). I'm using the JQuery framework.

I've tried several approaches and none worked, so an example won't be of much use. The idea is something like this:

```
function grid_constructor(options) {
  this.numOfdivisions = $(target).width() / division_size;

  $(this).on ("resize", function () {
       this.numOfdivisions = $(target).width() / division_size;
  })
}
```

So far I think the problem is that I should be binding the event to the document, not to the object, but when I try to bind the event to the document like this `$(window).resize (this.recalculate_divisions())`, it fires immediately, to never fire again (so I guess I'm doing it wrong).

As this function is inherent to the object, I cannot refer to the instantiated object by name (I don't know, at the time of writing the code, which name it will have), so I cannot simply do a `$(document).ready(function(){$(window).resize($(object_name).function))`.

Just for clarification. I do not want to create a custom event, I need my object to react to an event, at any time after construction.

Comment: `$(window).resize(func)` no `()`. [theoretical implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/CTX82/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what $(target) refers to, but you are correct, the 'resize' event needs to be bound to the window:

```
function grid_constructor(options) {
    var self = this,
        win = $(window);

    self.numOfdivisions = win.width() / division_size;

    win.on("resize", function () {
        self.numOfdivisions = win.width() / division_size;
    });
}
```

Comment: I just put an pseudo-snippet on the code. I'm doing an object that divides a DIV into squares. By the way, `self=this` worked like a charm! I cannot believe I didn't try this! Many thanks!

Comment: Awesome. I usually make it a habit of using `self=this` when writing anything involving callbacks since `this` can change meaning so often.

Comment: It should be obvious (at least it is for me now) but there aren't  many textbook examples or tutorials that suggest you to do that. I can only guess I'm going to start doing this from now on.